# SSIS Designer does not remember visible area

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS in Visual Studio 2008 with SP1.

When I load the designer of an existing package, it always shows an empty area. I have to scroll down and right to see my components or use the area scroller to get them visible.

It looks like a bug. Does anyone knows a workaround to save the x,y positions of the visible area in a package ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get around this problem by doing the following:

1. Set zoom to 100% (View -> Zoom -> 100%) Note: you may have to click in the designer pane to get Zoom to show on the view menu.
2. Scroll the window to where you want it be when you open up the package.
3. Select and move a task.
4. Save file

For step 3, I usually select the top task and press Ctrl-[left arrow], Ctrl-[right arrow]. I like tasks to stay where I put them! :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi doughall, you gave the right solution, thanks! After I got it to the right view area, I tried to zoom out and save it, but then it got a mess again. So it seams like a bug in storing the right area when a zoom is selected <> 100 %.

Answer (score 1):

Select all the components -choose format - Auto Layout - Diagram
Then save your package

Answer (score 1):

None of that worked for me in 2012.  My controls were in the very bottom left corner so I cut them....moved the zoom to middle range and then pasted the controls and that worked.